# Event creation&deletion emailing all users

Tags: apex, event, notification

I have an apex page that feeds itself from events created within the system with a checkbox to filter normal events from the events I need to display in the page.

When a new event is created or deleted, Salesforce is unintentionally emailing every user that exists within the system about a creation or deletion of the event. The apex page was working as it should and then started to show this behavior without any changes being made to the code.

The email went with subject: "Meeting cancelled: type of event"

The email text:

**Meeting Cancelled**

*Subject*           Meeting
*When*      04/12/2013 12:00 - 12:30 Brasilia Summer Time
*Where*

Comment: Sounds like someone maybe added a workflow?

Comment: There are no workflows created and I didn't include any options at all that were related to email notifications within the apex page.

Comment: Can you post the text of the email - that might give a clue as to where it's coming from.

Comment: A debug log (no workflows? OK. How about triggers?) might be useful too...

Comment: I'll edit the main post with the email text.

Comment: It sounds like this bug https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SvicAAC